# Pass Complex JSON Object to an MVC 3 Action

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3

I am getting some weird results while trying to pass a complex JSON object to an action in MVC 3.

The `Locations` are populated on the action parameter model, but the name and location are not.

If I do `ko.toJS(testViewModel)`, then the name and location are there, but the locations are blank???

I am using knockout.js:

```
var testViewModel = {
        Name: ko.observable("Joe Bob"),
        Locations: ko.observableArray([
            { ID: 1, Name: "Salem, OR" },
            { ID: 2, Name: "Big Bear Lake, CA" },
            { ID: 3, Name: "Big Bear City, CA" }
        ]),
        Position: ko.observable("Manager")
    }
```

Sending it via jQuery ajax:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/ClaimsAuthority/Home/TestIt",
            type: "POST",
            data: ko.toJSON(testViewModel),
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                //ko.applyBindings(data);
            }
        });
```

MVC Action:

```
<HttpPost()>
        Public Function TestIt(model As TestModel) As ActionResult
            Return Json(model)
        End Function
```

Models:

```
Public Class TestModel 
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Locations As ICollection(Of LocationModel)
    Public Property Position As String  
End Class

Public Class LocationModel
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
    Public ReadOnly Property DisplayText As String
        Get
            Return String.Format("({0}) {1}", ID, Name)
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try setting the content type to `application/json` in your AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/ClaimsAuthority/Home/TestIt',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: ko.toJSON(testViewModel),
    success: function (data, status, xhr) {
        //ko.applyBindings(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Darin!! That worked! I'll owe you another beer pretty soon!

Comment: Is it possible to parse complex models this way and receive them in the controller action as typed objects? Because I´m trying to do the same thing but the collection of the object, although with the instances, comes with empty property values.

Comment: @GustavoRubio, yes, it is possible to use arbitrarily complex objects and collections. Only circular object references are not supported because they cannot be JSON serialized.